# Wrong charset in HTTP Content-Type response

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, http

I have a japanese RHEL server running apache 2.0.

And this is my problem:
I want response with `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8` but currently it responses with `Content-Type: text/html; charset=Shift_JIS`

What I've tried:

- Add `AddDefaultCharset utf-8` to working `.htaccess` file (Can not edit apache config file)
- Add `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` to php file
- Add `php_value default_charset UTF-8` to `.htaccess` file
- Test with very simple `test.php`:

  `<?php
  header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
  ?>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="ja">
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
       <h1>Test</h1>
    </body>
  </html>`

None of above works. Someone please help me.

Comment: Have you tried sending a `content-type` *header* in the PHP file?

Comment: @Pekka웃: It does not work (question updated)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out that the problem was related to mbstring settings in php.ini.
It works when changing from

```
mbstring.language = Japanese
mbstring.http_input = auto
mbstring.http_output = SJIS
```

to

```
mbstring.language = Japanese
mbstring.http_input = pass
mbstring.http_output = pass
```

But at first, check [Álvaro González's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35770773/4335961) for this problem.

Answer (score 3):

As the name suggests, `AddDefaultCharset` changes the **default** charset. If there's another directive that sets a different Content-Type for your file type, your setting will be overridden.

In this case, PHP itself will always set the `Content-Type` header if you don't do it yourself so there's no way to configure it from Apache unless you run PHP as Apache module and use the `php_...` Apache directives.

Please check the [`default_charset` PHP directive](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.default-charset) for the details:

> All versions of PHP will use this value as the charset within the
>   default Content-Type header sent by PHP if the header isn't overridden
>   by a call to [header()](http://php.net/header).

*Obviously, anything you put in the response **body** (such as `<meta>` tags) does not alter the response **headers** sent earlier.*

Comment: Thank @Álvaro González. I've added `php_value default_charset UTF-8` to `.htaccess` file but no luck. I will try finding header() call in my php framework.

Comment: Even `header()` call does not work (question updated)